# How to return a json format respond instead of html in laravel for api

Tags: json, laravel, api, error-handling

I have Some API under work and when ever either the data is not found or the api is not found, i get the below type error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Not Found</title>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <div class="code">
            404 </div>

        <div class="message" style="padding: 10px;">
            Not Found </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

how can I get this same thing in JSON format? any best way to do this without modifying this kind of response in the web side of app!

Comment: You can do error handling for the same and return specific json response from the API. Please share your code for more help

Comment: Out of the box requests which accept json get json error responses. Is this not working for you?

Comment: I think the issue was I was using postman but the header was not sending the request as application/json.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in your `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` file, by extending your render funtion as follows

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Nothing found dude.'], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

the `->expectsJson` method responds to the HTTP header

```
Accept: application/json
```

It is important to send the header with all your API calls, this is i.e. for Vue.js projects in Laravel with Axios configured in `resoures/assets/js/bootstrap.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common={
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Accept': 'application/json', // here!
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + theToken,
};
```

The api will not answer with any html anymore. You may use Postman for testing/development.

Comment: so for every request, I send from the app, I will need to set the header to send as `Accept: application/json` ! then only this will work ?

Comment: currently, I tried a scenario where I had an `invalid token` and tried to provide it to the `auth:API` request. Is there a way to find if the token is invalid instead of the page not found, as I need to connect the API to the app and there how to identify if the token was invalid or we hit a dead end.

Comment: The token (JWT) authentification / authorisation would would handle with a middleware, different story

Comment: that is what i am saying, it send me the login screen instead of a json reply.

Answer (score 1):

In `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` -

Include `HttpException`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
```

Then find the `render()` function in the same file and there you can return JSON response instead of the default render:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
        return response()->json("Invalid endpoint.", 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Note  that you're only adding the 'if' and you're doing it before the `return parent::` line.

OR

You can return all exceptions in JSON like this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return response()->json($exception->getMessage(), $exception->getCode);
}
```

Comment: @princoo7 Updated answer to include returning all exceptions in JSON.